# How to pass value from fragment to fragment in viewpager?

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-viewpager

How to pass value from fragment to fragment in viewpager+tabslayout ?

DetailLeagueFragment.kt

```
class DetailLeagueFragment : Fragment(), DetailLeagueView {

    private var leagues: MutableList<DetailLeague> = mutableListOf()

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        val args = arguments
        val leagueId = args?.getString("idLeague")

        if (leagueId != null) {
            DetailLeaguePresenter(this).getDetailLeagueFromApi(leagueId)
        }

        viewpagerMatch.adapter = MatchPagerAdapter(childFragmentManager)
        tabLayoutMatch.setupWithViewPager(viewpagerMatch)
    }

    override fun showLoading() {
        progressBar.visible()
    }

    override fun hideLoading() {
        progressBar.gone()
    }

    override fun showDetailLeague(league: List<DetailLeague>) {
        leagues.clear()
        leagues.addAll(league)
        leagues.forEach {
            tvLeagueName.text = it.strLeague
            tvDescription.text = it.strDescriptionEN
            picasso(it.strBadge, imgLeagueBadge)
        }
    }
}
```

MatchPagerAdapter.kt

```
class MatchPagerAdapter(fragmentManager: FragmentManager) : FragmentPagerAdapter(fragmentManager) {

    override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
        return when (position) {
            0 -> {
                MatchFragment.newInstance("data From Fragment")
            }
            else -> {
                MatchFragment.newInstance("data From Fragment")
            }
        }
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int = 2

    override fun getPageTitle(position: Int): CharSequence? = when (position) {
        0 -> "Past Match"
        else -> "Next Match"
    }
}
```

MatchFragment.kt

```
class MatchFragment : Fragment() {

    companion object {
        fun newInstance(idLeague: String): MatchFragment {
            val bundle = Bundle()
            bundle.putString("idLeague", idLeague)
            val fragment = MatchFragment()
            fragment.arguments = bundle
            return fragment
        }
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        d("TAG", "idLeague : ${arguments?.getString("idLeague")}")
    }
}
```

How to pass data from DetailLeagueFragment

```
leagues.forEach {
    tvLeagueName.text = it.strLeague
    tvDescription.text = it.strDescriptionEN
    picasso(it.strBadge, imgLeagueBadge)
}
```

to MatchPagerAdapter ?

i want pass "idLeague" to DetailFragment(show DetailLeague) and to MatchPagerAdapter -> MatchFragment(show Match)

like DataFromFragment -> PagerAdapter -> Fragment or any idea to fix my problem ?

Comment: Please post code which is batter way to solve your problem.

Comment: use shared viewmodel

Comment: Use eventbus library for passing data to anywhere from anywhere in the application.! http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/

Answer (score 0):

Use **Bundle** to send String in one fragment to another :

```
// in your MatchFragment 
// Put the value in YourNewFragment is DetailLeagueFragment to pass data
DetailLeagueFragment ldf = new DetailLeagueFragment ();
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putString("YourKey", "YourValue");
ldf.setArguments(args);

//Inflate the fragment
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, ldf).commit();
```

Then in `onCreateView` of the new fragment:

```
//Retrieve the value
String value = getArguments().getString("YourKey");
```